# How do I show that $\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)| \geq \int_0^1|g(x)|dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I want to show that

$\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)| \geq \int_0^1|g(x)|dx$

for real-valued $g$ that is continuous for $0\leq x\leq1$ .

Is it enough to say that

$|g(x)| \leq \sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|$

and then that

$\int_0^1|g(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|dx = (\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|)(\int_0^1dx)=\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|$

or is there some obvious flaw that I have missed?

Comment: Yes, and you can replace the second inequality by an equality.

Comment: @user84413 Sorry yes, I did mean for the second inequality to be an equality. Edited.

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: Looks good to me as well. You should post your solution as an answer and accept it, so we can get this question marked as answered.

Comment: @kigen Awesome, thanks. I posted my answer but it says I am unable to accept it for 2 days - I guess I am too new a user or my rep is not high enough or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show

$\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)| \geq \int_0^1|g(x)|dx$

for real-valued $g$ that is continuous for $0\leq x\leq1$ .

It is clear that

$0 \leq |g(x)| \leq \sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|$

and then we see that

$\int_0^1|g(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|dx = (\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|)(\int_0^1dx)=\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|g(x)|$ .

Thus, the desired result is shown to be true.